# CSS: Generated content applied to blockquote only gets applied to first instance?

Tags: css

This CSS creates a nice effect when applied against a single blockquote within the content its attached to.

However, when there is more than one blockquote, everything works except the generated content.

In other words, the quote symbol is only applied to the first instance of the blockquote.

```
blockquote{
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    border-width:1px 0;
    margin:20px 0;
    padding: 2px 10px;
    padding-left:50px;
    font-style:italic;
    font-size:1.2em;
    font-weight:bold;
    quotes:'\201C';
    clear:both;
}
blockquote:before{
    content:open-quote;
    font-size:5em;
    position:absolute;
    color:#ccc;
    margin:0 0 0 -45px;
    font-family:georgia,serif;
    font-style:normal;
    font-weight:normal
}
```

***Update**: Thanks to Alex Morales, the issue is resolved by adding:*

```
blockquote:after{content:close-quote;position:absolute;visibility:hidden;}
```

Comment: What browsers have you tested in? Also, have you specified a close-quote for the :after pseudo-class? When I test in chrome it will repeat the opening quotes correctly only when I apply the close-quote after the content. Link here: http://jsfiddle.net/KhRBe/

Comment: That was it. I had to add blockquote:after{content:close-quote} Please submit your comment as answer and I'll select it.

Comment: Sweet, glad it helped. I will post now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to apply the close-quote for the :after pseudo-element. This should take care of your issue.

Here's some sample code:

```
blockquote:after{
content:close-quote;
font-weight:bold;
font-size:5em;
position:absolute;
color:#ccc;
margin:0 0 0 45px;
font-family:georgia,serif;
font-style:normal;
font-weight:normal
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Change your first statement to:

```
blockquote {
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    border-width:1px 0;
    margin:20px 0;
    padding: 2px 10px;
    padding-left:50px;
    font-style:italic;
    font-size:1.2em;
    font-weight:bold;
    quotes:'\201C''\201C';
}
```

[See jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GxBcF/)